# How to scale x-axis with a parameter which scals y axis as well while ploting?

Tags: plotting

```
x = ComplexExpand[(ωm^2 - ω^2 - I*ω*γm - (G^2*δ*ωm)/((k - I*ω)^2 + δ^2))]

k = 0.2
δ = 10
G = 0.3
γm = 0.000001
ωm = 10`

Plot[(Abs[(Re[x] + ω^2)^(1/2)]/ωm), (ω, -20,20},
  AxesLabel  -> (HoldForm[ω/ωm], HoldForm[ωeff1/ωm]),
  LabelStyle -> (GrayLevel[0], Bold),
  PlotStyle  -> (Thick, Green),
  PlotRange  -> All]
```

I want to scale on both axis with $\omega_{m}$ [y axis is scaled but not x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYQZR.jpg). While scaling with $\{\omega/\omega_{m}, -10,10\}$ in the above plot for x-axis, it shows some iteration error.

I tried with
$\Omega$= Range[-10,10];
t = $\Omega/\Omega_{m}$
and it shows
[strange behavior along y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvHB4.jpg).

How can I scale x-axis with $\Omega/\Omega_{m}$?

Comment: You cannot use List brackets (curly braces) as if they were parentheses. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html). You have not provided a definition for the parameter `a`

Comment: Depending on how you want to scale the x-axis, you need to do one of the following: Scale the limits of $\Omega$: `{Ω,-10Ωm, 10Ωm}`. Replace `Ω` with `Ω/Ωm` during the computation of your function - the easiest is probably to use `Block[{Ω=Ω/Ωm}, Abs[...]]`

Comment: @Bob I removed those braces and 'a' was a typo there

Comment: @Lukas thanks, scaling while computation worked for me rather than in plotting.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[(Abs[(Re[x] + ω^2)^(1/2)] /. ω -> ω1 ωm)/ωm,
 {ω1, -20/ωm, 20/ωm}, 
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[ω/ωm], HoldForm[ωeff1/ωm]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], Bold}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Green}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Alx Scaling along x-axis is fine but now, not scaled with \{omega_{m}} along y-axis.

Comment: Just divide to `ωm`.